# react-bootstrap-table2-paginator throwing error like Module not found: Can't resolve 'classnames'

Tags: reactjs, pagination

I'm getting following error while running my project in which I'm using react-bootstrap-table2-paginator. But I have installed the module, please find the image below...

```
./node_modules/react-bootstrap-table2-paginator/lib/src/pagination.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'classnames' in '/home/edu/pagination/node_modules/react-bootstrap-table2-paginator/lib/src'
```

[image: Module installation image below]

My app.js file is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';
import paginationFactory from 'react-bootstrap-table2-paginator';

const dataMovie = [{ id: 1, title: 'Conan the Barbarian', year: '1982' },
{ id: 2, title: 'Conan the Barbarian', year: '1983' },
{ id: 3, title: 'Conan the Barbarian', year: '1984' },
{ id: 4, title: 'Conan the Barbarian', year: '1985' },
{ id: 5, title: 'Conan the Barbarian', year: '1986' },
{ id: 1, title: 'Conan the Barbarian', year: '1982' },
{ id: 2, title: 'Conan the Barbarian', year: '1983' },
{ id: 3, title: 'Conan the Barbarian', year: '1984' },
{ id: 4, title: 'Conan the Barbarian', year: '1985' },
{ id: 5, title: 'Conan the Barbarian', year: '1986' },
{ id: 1, title: 'Conan the Barbarian', year: '1982' },
{ id: 2, title: 'Conan the Barbarian', year: '1983' },
{ id: 3, title: 'Conan the Barbarian', year: '1984' },
{ id: 4, title: 'Conan the Barbarian', year: '1985' },
{ id: 5, title: 'Conan the Barbarian', year: '1986' },
{ id: 1, title: 'Conan the Barbarian', year: '1982' },
{ id: 2, title: 'Conan the Barbarian', year: '1983' },
{ id: 3, title: 'Conan the Barbarian', year: '1984' },
{ id: 4, title: 'Conan the Barbarian', year: '1985' },
{ id: 5, title: 'Conan the Barbarian', year: '1986' } ];
const columns = [
  {
    datafield : 'id',
    text: 'ID'
  },
  {
    datafield:'title',
    name: 'Title',
  },
  {
    datafield: 'Year',
    name: 'year',

  },
];



class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BootstrapTable keyField='id' data={ dataMovie } columns={ columns } pagination={ paginationFactory() } />
    )
  }
};

export default App;
```

dependencies in package.json

```
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator": "^2.1.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
```

I have installed react-bootstrap-table2-paginator using the flowing command

```
 npm install react-bootstrap-table2-paginator --save
```

Comment: not getting that error on my side

Answer (score 0):

1. Add

```
"dependencies": {
     "classnames": "^2.2.6"
},
```

in /react-bootstrap-table2-paginator/package.json inside node_modules.

2. In /react-bootstrap-table2-paginator/  run: `npm update`.

see more https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2/pull/1491/files